# List users by a category

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, do-while

I have a SQL Server table that looks like this:

[image]

I need to display this data like so:

**North**

- Mark

**South**

- Sam
- Jim

**East**

- John
- Joe

**West**

- Bill

I don't necessarily need them in a list format that was just an example. I just need to be able to separate them by branch. From what I understand I need to use a DO WHILE statement? I just do not know how to formulate the proper code. This is my code so far.

ASPX Page

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="span12">
         <% 
            System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection pcn;
            System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand pcm;
            System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataReader prs;

            pcn = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("");
            pcm = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand();
            pcn.Open();
            pcm.Connection = pcn;

            var Sql = "SELECT * from Locations";

            pcm.CommandText = Sql;
            prs = pcm.ExecuteReader();
            var rowcount = 0;

            while (prs.Read())
            {
                rowcount++;
        %>

            <h4><%= prs["Branch"].ToString() %></h4>
            <%= prs["Name"].ToString() %>

        <%
            }
            prs.Close();
            pcn.Close();
        %>
```

Thank you ahead of time for assisting me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes AcId second idea is simplest 
First sort locations by branch and then do what he said like

```
        var Sql = "SELECT * from Locations Order by Branch";

        pcm.CommandText = Sql;
        prs = pcm.ExecuteReader();
        var rowcount = 0;
        var prvBranch="";

        while (prs.Read())
        {
            rowcount++;       
        if(prvBranch!=prs["Branch"].ToString())
        {%>
            <h4><%= prs["Branch"].ToString() %></h4>
        <%} %>
        <%= prs["Name"].ToString() %>

    <%
        prvBranch = prs["Branch"].ToString();

        }
        prs.Close();
        pcn.Close();
    %>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your SQL query, you should group by branch. Making the SQL statement something like:

```
SELECT * FROM Locations
GROUP BY Branch
```

Comment: Doing this does separate the branches but it doesn't look entirely right. For instance now I have: EAST - John, EAST - Joe, rather than EAST - John Joe.

Comment: @kcray Okay, now I see what you're trying to do. I don't think there is a way to have SQL output the branch only once for each group, so I think your best option is to make a check in you code for every tabel row, if the branch is the same as the previous.

Answer (score 0):

you need to update the sql query to get the required output from database

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using pivot table?
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/spike/archive/2009/03/03/pivot-tables-in-sql-server-a-simple-sample.aspx